# passport google token cookie

Tags: reactjs, passport.js

I have a client in netlify, there is an api in heroku. I'm making a login system using google passport, but when the cookie is sent to the client from the api, the cookies are lost when the page is refreshed, what is the reason for this, I provide the netlify api communication with a proxy

server index.js

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "https://myexample.app",
    credentials: true,
    methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    allowedHeaders: [
      "Origin",
      "X-Requested-With",
      "Content-Type",
      "Accept",
      "Authorization",
    ],
    preflightContinue: true,
  })
);

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  next();
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
      httpOnly: false,
    },
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoDBStore({
      uri: "url",
      collection: "sessions",
    }),
  })
);
```

Comment: Add the frontend code  as well  . maybe you didn't save them in local storage that's why you loose the cookies when you refresh the window

Comment: I don't do much on the client side, I just redirect it to the api login router with a href.